# AWS SNS notification are not sent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using AWS SDK to send SNS, but notification are not going out.

```
final AmazonSNSClient client = new AmazonSNSClient( new BasicAWSCredentials( "xxxx", "zzzzzzzzzzzz") );
final PublishRequest request = new PublishRequest("arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123455:DEV_WEBSERVICE_ERROR", "This is test", "DEV-Publish");
final PublishResult result = client.publish( request );
System.out.println(result.getMessageId());
client.shutdown();
```

I have created a topic and arn is mentioned in the request. When I execute this code, it does no send out notification.

Please let me know, what wrong is going there.I am using AWS JAVA SDK 1.5.6

-Thanks
Subhash

Comment: Have you added any subscriptions to the topic?  If so, what kind?

Comment: I figured out the problem.There were different topic created in different region (us-west-1 and us-east-1) but with same name. ( Don't know who did it) And the one which is in use had no subscription. I added subscription to the one which is use that is (us-east-1) and it started working beautifully.